# How to ensure which version of Excel is opened using VSTO 4?

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

I am population an Excel sheet using VSTO as follow:

```
Application app = new Application();
var wBook = app.Workbooks.Add();
var wSheet = (wBook.Worksheets[1] as Worksheet);
/* Population algorithm */
app.Visible=true;
```

The sheet is created and everything is fine, except that I have two versions of Excel installed in the envrionment I work in (Excel 2003 and Excel 2010).

Last week, when I first created the code, Excel 2010 was showing up. However, this week, it's Excel 2003 that opens up.

My project references `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` with the latest version (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`, Version 14).

Is this somehow a preference in Windows, or is it something I have to specify when I create the instance of the application?

Comment: Alternatively you could target the 2003 PIO and then it wouldn't matter which Excel opens.

Comment: @Jesse I don't understand, what's the PIO? Besides, I'm looking to have the 2010 opened.

Comment: Sorry, PIA.  The dll that your referencing.  They're forward compatible ie the PIA for 2003 will automate 2010 but you won't be able to reference new features.

Comment: Your current version of office is 2003. Repairing the office 2010 will solve u r problem....

Answer (score 0):

maybe start excel 2010 and get handle to it, below code may help

```
 public static void GetReferences(ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _Application, ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _Workbook) 
{ 
    EnumChildCallback cb; 
    // start exe
    int hwnd = Process.Start("Excel 2010 path").MainWindowHandle; 


    if (hwnd != 0) 
    { 
        int hwndChild = 0; 
        cb = new EnumChildCallback(EnumChildProc); 
        EnumChildWindows(hwnd, cb, ref hwndChild); 


        if (hwndChild != 0) 
        { 
            const uint OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0xFFFFFFF0; 
            Guid IID_IDispatch = new Guid( 
                 "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"); 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window ptr = null; 

            int hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow( 
                  hwndChild, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch.ToByteArray(), ref ptr); 
            if (hr >= 0) 
            {                
                _Application = ptr.Application; 
                _Workbook = _Application.ActiveWorkbook; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 

[DllImport("Oleacc.dll")] 
public static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow( 
      int hwnd, uint dwObjectID, byte[] riid, 
      ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window ptr); 

public delegate bool EnumChildCallback(int hwnd, ref int lParam); 

[DllImport("User32.dll")] 
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows( 
      int hWndParent, EnumChildCallback lpEnumFunc, 
      ref int lParam); 


[DllImport("User32.dll")] 
public static extern int GetClassName( 
      int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount); 

public static bool EnumChildProc(int hwndChild, ref int lParam) 
{ 
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(128); 
    GetClassName(hwndChild, buf, 128); 
    if (buf.ToString() == "EXCEL7") 
    { 
        lParam = hwndChild; 
        return false; 
    } 
    return true;
```

}